# React Routes - different styling on body css tag

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have two routes on my React app: `/a` and `/b`.

For **/a**, I want the `body` css tag to have a **`background-color: red;`**.

For **/b**, I want the `body` css tag to have a **`background-color: blue;`**.

Both components `a` and `b` live in different .JSX files, and both import their own `main.scss` file which defines their own respective `body` `background-color`.

However, since the entire app is compiled into the `body` tag, there seems to be a conflict, and only one of the `body` tags is respected for both routes.

```
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
```

The reason I want it on the `body` tag and not just a container div is that I want the `background-color` to be visible when I scroll outside the bounds of the page (the bounce effect on Mac and iOS).

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Are you using CSS modules? Or just importing the css?

Comment: @QoP importing the css

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's happening because when you import your styles in your component without CSS Modules, the styles are global so your **body** style is defined two times (you can see all the styles in the `<head>` tag).

[image]

You can fix that by setting the background color in your component componentDidMount() method.

Example

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"// Set the style
    document.body.className="body-component-a" // Or set the class
}
```

Answer (score 4):

or, if youre using functional components you can do the same with useEffect...

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = 'class-name';
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what QoP said but, as an add on to that, you should also make sure to use componentWillUnmount to set it back to whatever it normally is outside that component.

for example:
if normally for the whole application text-align is left but for one component you want it to be center, but after the component it needs to return to being left, you will do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.textAlign = "center"
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.body.style.textAlign = "left"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

> ```
> componentDidMount(){
>     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
> }
> ```

Hope to help.